# How to duplicate MySQL rows based on row name (1) and change the row name afterwards (2)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a WP multi site with lots of sub sites.

1. I want to duplicate all rows with the option_name "theme_mods_my-theme".
2. And change it after duplication to "theme_mods_my-new-theme".
3. The original "theme_mods_my-theme" must not be deleted or changed.

The row name is unique but there are multiple tables where this row appears. 
The value of these rows is **unique**. 
The row name appears in these tables for example:

- mywpsite_18_options // subsite ID 18
- mywpsite_17_options // subsite ID 17
- mywpsite_16_options // subsite ID 16
- etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

I think I need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `mywpsite_17_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`)
VALUES
(31940, 'theme_mods_my-theme', '[The values]', 'yes');
```

The only thing is:

1. It needs to search for all tables with the name mywpsite_XX_options
2. Find theme_mods_my-theme in the option_name column for each table
3. Duplicate (insert) it like above into each table
4. [The values] need to be duplicated
5. theme_mods_my-theme needs to be changed into theme_mods_my-new-theme
6. I guess the option_id needs to change as well since it is a new insert.

Comment: row name ??  the row in db have not name  you mean the content of a  column for a row .. which are the related  columns  name??

Comment: Sorry yes, I mean option_name, thats the column name I want to search in and I want to search for theme_mods_my-theme in that column, and then duplicate it including the value.

Comment: update your question  and add a sample of the rows you want duplicare..  anyway each operation must repated  for each table  you want to duplicate

Comment: What have you tried already? We need an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) to help you.

Comment: @scaisEdge, I updated my question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

instead of duplication and update you could use a insert select  eg:

```
   insert into mywpsite_18_options (col_theme_name, col2, col3 )
   select 'theme_mods_my-new-theme', col2, col3
   from mywpsite_18_options
   where col_theme_name =  'theme_mods_my-theme'
```

but you must repated  the operation for each table

Comment: I updated my question with some more info. Ok so there is no way to go trough the complete database and automate this? And how do I copy the value of theme_mods_my-theme and paste it into theme_mods_my-new-theme?

Comment: yes but if you adapted  the insert select  ..  you can easy poulate the table you need ..  anyway be careful with the id  ..  be sure you use correct values in the insert/select  ..and for autoincrement you don't need  column and value